# SCSS file cannot import node_module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

Tried @import "~react-icons" in an SCSS file.

I get an error: Module build failed:
    @import "~react-icons";
    ^
          File to import not found or unreadable: ~react-icons.

This was an npm module that I installed and is on package-json.

My scss code looks like this, the error is at the first line:

```
@import "~react-icons";

input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

My webpack configuration looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
let APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

let config = {
    entry: path.join(APP_DIR, '/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loaders: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  fallback: "style-loader",
                  use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                  publicPath: "/dist"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?(\?v=
                     [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
        // serve index.html in place of 404 responses to allow HTML5 
        // history
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'Project',
          minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true
          },
          hash: true,
          template: './index.html'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'style.css',
          disable: false,
          allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Will you please also post the code where you are trying to import the scss file ?

Comment: React Icons is a package with es6 icons and not css. Right?

Comment: @VivekDoshi the code has been added.

Comment: may i know why are you importing @import "~react-icons"; ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi so that I can use react-icons fa-search as my background-image for my styles. I tried importing bootstrap, and the terminal gives me the same error

Comment: Do you have ~react-icons.scss file ? on same folder ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi no i dont have any scss file related to react-icons on any folder. Does this error have something to do with node-sass / webpack configuration

Comment: Then what are you trying to import via @import "~react-icons"; ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I'm trying to import react-icon/lib/fa/fa-search

Answer (score 0):

There is not an scss file to import for [react-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icons). You have to import the icons in the file you want to use:

```
import FaSearch from 'react-icons/lib/fa/search';

class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <FaSearch />
    }
}
```